# iphone view flipping: viewflips from top to bottom instead of right to left

Tags: iphone, sdk, view, core-animation, flip

i try to build a app that is in landsscape mode all the time.
I did the usual stuff:
plist added UIInterfaceOrientation / UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
rotated the XIBs in interface builder with the little arrow in top of view.

```
my code for launching:
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    FlipViewController *flip = [[FlipViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipViewController" bundle:nil];
    [window addSubview:flip.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

But when i try to do a "UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft" the page flips from top to bottom instead of right to left. :-/

This is the code i use to flip the views:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.25];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    UIViewController *coming = nil;
    UIViewController *going = nil;
    UIViewAnimationTransition transition;

    if (self.blueViewController.view.superview == nil) 
    {   
        coming = blueViewController;
        going = yellowViewController;
        transition = UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft;
    }
    else
    {
        coming = yellowViewController;
        going = blueViewController;
        transition = UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight;
    }

    [UIView setAnimationTransition: transition forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [coming viewWillAppear:YES];
    [going viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [going.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview: coming.view atIndex:0];
    [going viewDidDisappear:YES];
    [coming viewDidAppear:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

"window" seems to have missed the fact, that it is in landsscape-mode. Hmmm.
can anyone spot my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with documented methods.

You need to [use CATransition](http://webbuilders.wordpress.com/2009/04/05/catransition-vs-uiview-beginanimations/). (CATransition itself is documented, but the *flip transition* is not.)

To use the flip transition, set the transition's `type` to "oglFlip" and set `subtype` to fromLeft/Top/Right/Bottom.

Comment: ups. way more complicated then i thought.
Using undocumented "oglFlip" will most likely deny me from getting my app into the apstore?